# Currency symbol in numeric value based on object property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting

How to show a numeric (currency) value in `WPF` so that the currency symbol would not come from the user's regional settings, locale or anything but from the property of the binded object.

For example in `DataGrid` I would have `Item` objects:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SomeNumber, StringFormat=c}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>

public Item()
{
    public double SomeNumber { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
}
```

The above standard `"c"`formatting will show currency symbol based on some user setting and ignoring the business object.

But the value should be displayed like this

SomeNumber = 3456234.67 (positive numbers)

```
CurrencySymbol ="€" > €3 456 234.67
CurrencySymbol ="$" > $3 456 234.67
CurrencySymbol ="₽" > ₽3 456 234.67
```

SomeNumber = -3456234.67 (negative numbers)

```
CurrencySymbol ="€" > (€3 456 234.67)
CurrencySymbol ="$" > ($3 456 234.67)
CurrencySymbol ="₽" > (₽3 456 234.67)
```

SomeNumber= 0 (zero values)

```
CurrencySymbol ="€" > -
CurrencySymbol ="$" > -
CurrencySymbol ="₽" > -
```

Is there a way to get the currency symbol to the value this way with `StringFormat`?

Comment: Use a Binding Converter that converts an `Item` to string.

Comment: var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName == ci.DisplayName)
    {
        ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    }

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to automatically attach the currency symbol to a number using `StringFormat` is by using a ConverterCulture:

```
<!-- This will be shown as '¥1,423.7' -->
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=SomeNumber,
                                      StringFormat=c,
                                      ConverterCulture='ja-JP'}"/>

<!-- This will be shown as '1.423.70 €' -->
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=SomeNumber,
                                      StringFormat=c,
                                      ConverterCulture='de-DE'}"/>
```

The good thing about it is that the number is also formatted according to requested `ConverterCulture`.

In your case you want to format the number yourself (notice the position of the currency symbol is changing according to the `ConverterCulture` as well), also, ***you want to decide what will be the currency displayed yourself***, which makes it impossible to relay on the `ConverterCulture`.

In this case, ***the correct way to do it will be creating an `IValueConverter` yourself***:

```
public class CurrencyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Item valueAsItem = value as Item;
        if (valueAsItem != null)
        {
            double amount = valueAsItem.SomeNumber;
            if (amount == 0)
            {
                return "-"; //In the question this is the display for 0.
            }
            if (amount < 0)
            {
                amount *= -1; //In the question the numbers always display positive.
            }
            //In the question this is the format for the numbers.
            return valueAsItem.CurrencySymbol + amount.ToString("### ### ###.###");
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in the `.xaml`:

- Inside the `Window` Attribute:

  ```
  <Window.Resources>
      <local:CurrencyConverter 
    x:Key="CurrencyConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
  ```
- And for the `DataGrid`:

  ```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount"
                              Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CurrencyConverter}}"/>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
  ```

Now when the `DataContext` is as the following:

```
public class MyDataContext
{
    public ICollectionView MyItems { get; set; }

    public MyDataContext()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { CurrencySymbol = "$", SomeNumber = 123.4 },
            new Item { CurrencySymbol = "₹", SomeNumber = 0 },
            new Item { CurrencySymbol = "₹", SomeNumber = -14345623.7 }
        };

        MyItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public double SomeNumber { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
}
```

The grid looks like that:

[image: WPF Binding]

as requested.

More info on `double` formatting [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).